# Pass required positional argument to super class without adding it in subclass' constructor

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have such a class:

```
class C1:

    def __init__(self, arg1, kwarg1=1, kwarg2=2):
        ...
```

Now I want to create a `C2` that just changes default values of `kwarg1` and `kwarg2` in `C1`. It's some sort of `functools.partial` but for classes.

I can do it it this way:

```
class C2(C1):

    def __init__(self, arg1, kwarg1=3, kwarg2=4):
        super().__init(arg1, kwarg1=kwarg1, kwarg2=kwarg2)
```

But I don't like that I need to pass `arg1` to `C2` constructor and then pass it as it is to `C1` with `super().__init(arg1, ...)`.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
class C2(C1):

    def __init__(self, kwarg1=3, kwarg2=4, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init(kwarg1=kwarg1, kwarg2=kwarg2, *args, **kwargs)
```

but this doesn't work:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg1'
```

Is there any way I can pass `arg1` to `C1` from `C2` without mentioning it in `C2`'s constructor

Comment: Is `arg1` the same for all instances of `C2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it on an even more convoluted way, but at least you won't be passing the dreaded `arg1`:

```
class C2(C1):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["kwarg1"] = kwargs.get("kwarg1", 3)
        kwargs["kwarg2"] = kwargs.get("kwarg2", 4)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

But you'll still need to keep your positional arguments when initializing `C2`.